# send sms in the background programmatically in iphone using phonegap 2.9.0

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, message, cordova-2.0.0

I know we can use

> MFMessageComposeViewController

to compose message and forward the SMS

My question is how can we send an SMS in the background ???

I am working on an application which has prefixed number of recipients and a fixed message body . 
The user has to press a send button only once and this predefined message will be forwarded to all the recipients in the background .

The user should NOT be taken to messages application where he can edit the message body , add/remove recipients and then send the message

If there are any third party api then can they be used along with phonegap ?? and will the app be rejected ??

Kindly help !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is no documented solution. You may use undocumented approach, it is technically possible, but there is no way for You to AppStore then.

Comment: can you tell us...how?

Comment: private headers collection. you can find there everything you need. but. as I said, forget about App Store

Answer (score 0):

I only know native (ObjC) coding, not PhoneGap, but PhoneGap can't do more than native coding so I can tell you quite clearly that there is no way to send an SMS without opening the `MFMessageComposeViewController`. This is done to protect users from having messages sent without their consent. There is no way around this.